# How to remove column number from p:barChart

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

[image]I am using primefaces p:barChart which is a part of the jqplot api.

I want to remove the column number (the lest number 1 ) from the jqplot-highlighter-tooltip()
I assume the answer is in one of the options in the following 
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html but I didn't find the correct one

Can someone can please point me to the relevant attr ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the column value from the tooltip? Could you include a screenshot or point to an existing one?

Answer (score 2):

```
function ext() {
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
        tooltipAxes: 'y'
    };
}
```